# Omitting c# new from jagged array initialization

Tags: c#, new-operator, jagged-arrays

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Notice that you cannot omit the new operator from the elements initialization because there is no default initialization for the elements:

```
int[][] jaggedArray3 = 
{
    new int[] {1,3,5,7,9},
    new int[] {0,2,4,6},
    new int[] {11,22}
};
```

What does it mean?

Why is it ok to omit new in:

```
int[]    arrSimp = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[,]   arrMult = { { 1, 1 }, { 2, 2 }, { 3, 3 } };
```

but not possible in:

```
int[][,] arrJagg = {new int[,] { { 1, 1} }, new int[,] { { 2, 2 } }, new int[,] { { 3, 3 } } };
```

Comment: There could be a technical reason such as a syntax ambiguity, or some corner cases that made the lexical analysis overly complex. The C# designers tend to err on the side of simplicity (or the status quo) in such cases especially when the probability of usage is low and there is fairly equivalent syntax that doesn't break a programmer's back to use.

Comment: Maybe it's just that allowing it would allow for some nightmarish parsing cases...

Comment: @ChrisSinclair That would be ok, but I do not understand the explanation which they had given (there is no default initialization). Is int foo[] initialized by default without using new?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, what a coincidence, an aspect of your question is the subject of my blog today:

http://ericlippert.com/2013/01/24/five-dollar-words-for-programmers-elision/

You've discovered a small "wart" in the way C# classifies expressions. As it turns out, the array initializer syntax `{1, 2, 3}` is not an *expression*. Rather, it is a syntactic unit that can only be used as part of another expression:

```
new[] { 1, 2, 3 }
new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }
new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 }
new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3 } }
... and so on
```

or as part of a collection initializer:

```
new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }
```

or in a variable declaration:

```
int[] x = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

It is **not** legal to use the array initializer syntax in any other context in which an expression is expected. For example:

```
int[] x;
x = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

is not legal.

It's just an odd corner case of the C# language. There's no deeper meaning to the inconsistency you've discovered.

Comment: That just happens. :) I just wanted to dig deeper into corner cases of C# (what would happen if I did this or that and why it will not work), MSDN is not very precise what is {1, 2, 3} and even it is a syntactic sugar I hoped it would work on jagged arrays too. Seems I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In essence the answer is "because they (meaning the language designers) choose not to.To quote from Eric Lippert:

> The same reason why every unimplemented feature is not implemented:
>   features are unimplemented by default. In order to become implemented
>   a feature must be (1) thought of, (2) designed, (3) specified, (4)
>   implemented, (5) tested, (6) documented and (7) shipped.

More technically there is a good reason to it and that's the definition of jagged arrays compared to 1-dimension and multi-dimension arrays.

A one or more dimension arrays can be expressed in plain English as a X dimension array of T where a jagged array has to be expressed as an Array of arrays of T. In the second case, there is a loose coupling between the inner array and the outer arary. That is, you can assign a new array to a position within the outer array whereas a x dimension array is fixed.

Now that we know that Jagged arrays are very different from multi-dimensional arrays in their implementation, we can also assume why there is a different level of integrated support for the 2. It's certainly not impossible to add support, just a question of demand and time.

(as a teaser, why only add support for jagged arrays? how about your own custom types?)

Comment: For me it seems it like it is a bit of missing syntactic sugar. In plain C jagged array could be easily implemented by an array holding pointers.